# Get calling app in Android Source

Tags: android, android-source

I am modifying Android 4.4 to log calls to several Manager methods. For example SMSManagers [sendTextMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method.

I want to be able to extract the calling App (which is responsible for sending the SMS) but when I observe the call stack in the `sendTextMessage()` method via `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` it does not seem to deliver this information.

**How can I get the App that initiates the SMS sending procedure?**

Here is an example json output (dont mind the format) of my logger when sending an SMS:

```
{"trace":
[{"clazz":"android.telephony.SmsManager","method":"sendTextMessage"},
{"clazz":"android.telephony.SmsManager","method":"sendMultipartTextMessage"},
{"clazz":"com.android.mms.transaction.SmsSingleRecipientSender","method":"sendMessage"},
{"clazz":"com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService","method":"sendFirstQueuedMessage"},
{"clazz":"com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService","method":"handleSendMessage"},
{"clazz":"com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService","method":"access$400"},
{"clazz":"com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService$ServiceHandler","method":"handleMessage"},
{"clazz":"android.os.Handler","method":"dispatchMessage"},
{"clazz":"android.os.Looper","method":"loop"},
{"clazz":"android.os.HandlerThread","method":"run"}
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you mistaking threads and tasks?

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = 
     am.getRecentTasks(10000,ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);
```

would give you a task list, in there you should find the sender for intents your application is receiving.

Because Thread.currentThread will always reference the thread your app is running in, which was started by the activity manager, you wont get to the sender of the intent through your thread. Even worse, stacktrace is not related at all to another thread.
What you see in your logger is the stacktrace from within the SMSManagers - Thread.

To clearify: One process may span as many threads as it wants to (restricted by resource usage and some other limitations as the defined maximum number of processes or file descriptors). This process is the parent process of all other threads. 
The Activity Manager itself relies on Zygote, which is responsible for tasks as starting activities or putting them into the background, the ActivityManager provides a Java - Interface to it (as Zygote itself is part of the OS). Threads know about the parent processes (pid()) but not necessarily anything about other threads executing in parallel in the environment. Stacktraces are process related. Because threads are light - weighted processes, they have there own stacktraces. In a stacktrace contained are only informations that adresses the processes adress space, which is restricted to the thread's process itself.

And even more precise: Even when relating to the tasks currently in the stack (this is the task - stack, not to be confused with the stack you will get by getBackTrace), there will only be a random guess on who's sending the intent. It even maybe that the task which was sending the intent already has been killed and not existing any longer.
This is part of the android design, a intent does not generally contain a reference to its sender. If you wonder why: Again, the sender of an Intent and the receiver maybe objects living in different adress spaces or processes. So a direct reference to that object could not be passed from one thread to another without sharing a portion of the adress spaces. But this is advanced thread handling and IPC. PendingIntent contains a method called getIntentSender. But it's on the implementers side to give a PendingIntent to a receiver which then can use it to start other processes (activities, services, ...). So unless you can't retrieve a pending intent from the  SMSManager you won't get the sender of the intent by api calls. Instead you can try the work around by examining the task  stack as described above.

Comment: So basically is left that you can monitor your calls of specific methods of the different managers in android, but can't monitor calls from other apps to the same methods directly. You can just monitor the tasks and processes on the system. When using a rooted device, you could examine the adress spaces of this processes, too, but this is a far complex process including reverse engineering (to map from symbols in the adress space to methods).

Comment: Well, thanks for clearifying this up. So, do i get this right, there is no direct way to get a "TaskTrace", I have to find my tasks in the list of recently executed Tasks?

Comment: Would it be a nice idea, or is it possible to log the creation of Intents that want to send SMS **in the Intent classes** instead of SMSManager to get the requested information?

Comment: At your first comment:Yes. And when monitoring the task - stack steadily you could get an impression of which task started which so this would be an information about which app is using which system service though leaving unspecified which methods of the service are called. When monitoring additional resources such as devices (wlan - chip, sms - devices) you could even get a impression of which method the app might be using for some of the services.

Comment: At your second comment: It would be a nice idea but does require recompiling the complete android sources and reinstalling them unto the device. Because the sources within the Intent - Classes are part of the OS.

Comment: You could even try an approach of manipulating or exchanging the class loader of the vm and replacing the Intent - classes with your own implementations, but again, this would only be possible on a rooted device and actually falls into the category of hacking which is not acceptable to me.

Comment: This work is for a research project at university. I am already compiling the complete sources - which is already necessary for getting the above logging output directly from the SMSManager implementation. So far we are only targeting rooted devices, so the effort is acceptable for me : ) Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer that you cannot tell who the sender of an `Intent` was, however, in case you have several SMS/MMS apps installed on the device and you want to know which one called `sendMultipartTextMessage()`, you can add the function in **SmsManager.java** the following lines:

> ```
> public void sendMultipartTextMessage(
>         String destinationAddress, String scAddress, ArrayList<String> parts,
>         ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents, ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents) {
>     if (TextUtils.isEmpty(destinationAddress)) {
>         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid destinationAddress");
>     }
>     if (parts == null || parts.size() < 1) {
>         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid message body");
>     }
>     /*** New Lines ***/
>     int uid = android.os.UserHandle.getCallingUserId();
>     int appId = android.os.UserHandle.getAppId(uid);
>     /* Now you have the application id so you know which app called this function */
> ```

Using the appId you can ask PackageManager which package owns this id.
If you'd rather have the pid, you can use the `Binder`, but you can't really do anything with the pid